Should I be concerned at Command line refusal to recognize .zshrc?
I know nothing about command line instruction. When I open Terminal after installing Homebrew I am told my .zprofile is not recognised.

By researching the issue I find the ‘nano’ instruction can be used to re-set the path. The file name is shown at bottom of screen: /Users/tony01/.zshrc which is reassuring.

Yet when I close and re-open Terminal the .zprofile file message remains.
Given my ignorance of the command line, I do not know how serious this issue is but I would appreciate help in fixing it.

Are you confusing .zshrc and .zprofile? They are not the same file.

I understand they are different commands. As above, Tony 01: Terminal tells me ‘there is no such command or directory’. I do not understand why this message has been generated as installation of Homebrew is largely automatic.
